# How to open a file by double clicking in C# WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, file

I need the file to open when the user double-clicks it in explorer, just like if you double-clicked a .txt file to open in Notepad. My program simply opens to the starting window, rather than the edit window. I want the start window to get it and pass it to the edit window. I can pass it to the edit window, but I can't figure out how to get the file path to the start window.

I have tried getting the environment arguments, which returns something weird, and not the file that the user double clicked.

I am not asking how to associate files with my program, which I can find out. I am only asking about how to open the file the user double-clicks in explorer.

Here's my code:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Container.Children.Clear();
            Container.Children.Add(new NewFilePage());

            if (Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().ToString() != null)
            {
                new EditorWindow(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().ToString()).Show();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. File association;
2. Modify ***App.xaml*** and ***App.xaml.cs*** in the WPF Application:
   In App.xaml, remove the *StartUp* tag. Then subscribe to the Startup event, replacing the StartupUri property.

   ```
    <Application x:Class="WpfTutorialSamples.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             Startup="Application_Startup">
    <Application.Resources></Application.Resources>
   ```

The event is then implemented in App.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class App : Application
    {

        private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            MainWindow wnd = new MainWindow();
            if(e.Args.Length == 1)
                wnd.FullFilePath = e.Args[0];
            wnd.Show();
        }
    }
```

After these, the command-line parameters would be stored in `e.Args`. You can send these data to a property of your MainWindow class.

[image: Demo]

Comment: The OP specifically said "I am not asking how to associate files with my program".

Comment: This was the exact solution I needed! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I follow what the problem is here.

I created an app with mainwindow and window1.  I then overload the constructor of each window so they take a string parameter.

Application startup grabs the parameter and passes it in:

```
    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        string passed = string.Empty;
        if (e.Args.Length > 0)
        {
            passed = e.Args[0].ToString();
        }
        var mw = new MainWindow(passed);
        mw.Show();
    }
```

Since this is just a quick n dirty proof of concept I then pass in the parameter to window1 and show it.

That sets the text of a textblock successfully:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1(string passed)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        tb.Text=passed;
    }
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

It has the full file path.

[image]

You could then do whatever you need to do with that file.